# Content Query Webpart date issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I have a content query web part which display data from a list. 
Web part shows date from Modified column.
But the date display on web part for Modified is [Modified + 1].

e.g. Assume that document is modified on 5 December, so web part shows date 6 December.

Please suggest some workaround.

Comment: Do you write any custom Item Style for CQWP?